# iOS - animate movement of a label or image

Tags: animation, ios4, ios

How can I animate the movement of a label or image? I would just like to make a slow transition from one location on the screen to another (nothing fancy).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're looking for the `-beginAnimations:context:` and `-commitAnimations` methods on [UIView](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html).

In a nutshell, you do something like:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL]; // animate the following:
myLabel.frame = newRect; // move to new location
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 13):

For ios4 and later you should not use `beginAnimations:context` and `commitAnimations`, as these are discouraged in the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html).

Instead you should use one of the block-based methods.

The above example would then look like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{  // animate the following:
    myLabel.frame = newRect; // move to new location
}];
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example with a `UILabel` - the animation slides the label from the left in 0.3 seconds.

```
// Save the original configuration. 
CGRect initialFrame = label.frame;

// Displace the label so it's hidden outside of the screen before animation starts.
CGRect displacedFrame = initialFrame;
displacedFrame.origin.x = -100;
label.frame = displacedFrame;

// Restore label's initial position during animation. 
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    label.frame = initialFrame;
}];
```