# After segue animate label to new x origin

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

I been trying to animate a label after the segue is done where it will come from right then to its original position (which is the middle of the view controller). My code is fairly similar to [this](http://www.appcoda.com/storyboards-ios-tutorial-pass-data-between-view-controller-with-segue/)

and my animation code that should work, but unfortunately it does not work at all,

```
 CGRect newFrame = myLabel.frame;
    newFrame.origin.x += 1000;    // shift right by 500pts

    [UIView animateWithDuration:3.0
                     animations:^{
                         myLabel.frame = newFrame;
                         [myLabel setText:row];
                     }];
```

would appreciate some help, as I am learning atm.

Comment: you max x can be 320 (iphone) and 768 (ipad) if you go beyond that your ui frame move out the visible screen i.e. x + x + x... = 320 or 768

Comment: see post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21925691/how-to-add-animations-on-label

Comment: Turn your autolayout off - and set new frame directly in animation block