# UILabel Animation in a Function Returning UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiimageview, uilabel

I am having trouble with animating my UILabels in iOS. I used this thread as a reference ([iOS - animate movement of a label or image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663988/ios-animate-movement-of-a-label-or-image)), but it doesn't seem to work for me. I've also tried several others, and they also don't work.

I simply want to smoothly move a label to another location in a set amount of time (by smoothly I mean no jumps). However, when I tested it, the labels do not move. Here is my code. I've shortened it to what I think could be the problem. Because everything besides the animation works.

```
- (UIImageView *)createImageWithTransitionTo:(NSMutableArray *) nextPOIs
{
    //imageView is a UIImageView which will be the return value of this function
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed@"blank1.gif"]];

    //Initialize label and manipulate it for my needs
    UILabel * label = /.../;        

    //Create animation
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
        label.frame = nextLabelFrame; //nextLabelFrame is a CGRect
    }];

    [imageView addSubView:label];
    return imageView;
}
```

My intuition tells me that it's because the animation is for UIView and I am adding label as a sub-view to a UIImageView object (i.e. imageView). However, I've also tried [UIImageView animateWithDuration ..]. Is it because I'm using it in a function outside of the view controller? How can I fix it?

Comment: Why are you adding `label` as a subview of `imageView`?

Comment: Because I want to add multiple labels to imageView. My full code for this is encased in a for-loop where I set the location of labels with some calculations. Do you propose that there's a better way to do this?

Comment: Please clarify what is your final objective. From seeing your code you are adding some labels to an image view and then animating it here itself, and then returning that image view. So basically you should be adding the image view to some other view(say _self.view_) after that method returns it to you but animation is finished already so how will you get to see this on your screen? I might have misunderstood it but that's what your question description says.

Comment: My apologies. The point with the code above is to separate the lengthy calculations that goes with determining the label position. Initially, I only thought about dealing with labels without transition animations and it worked fine. Are you saying that the animation happens when I call animateWithDuration? In that case, should I create the animation after I return the imageView?

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you are doing great.
In my point of view, you need to slightly change your code. I am reposting your piece of code with a slight change. (pardon me , if i am wrong)

```
- (UIImageView *)createImageWithTransitionTo:(NSMutableArray *) nextPOIs
```

{
    //imageView is a UIImageView which will be the return value of this function
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed@"blank1.gif"]];

```
//Initialize label and manipulate it for my needs
UILabel * label = /.../;
```

//Add label before animating

```
[imageView addSubView:label];

//Create animation
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    label.frame = nextLabelFrame; //nextLabelFrame is a CGRect
}];


return imageView;
```

}

Comment: Abdul, thanks for your help, but I still have the same problem when I add it before animating it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one i think its work.

```
- (UIImageView *)createImageWithTransitionTo:(NSMutableArray *) nextPOIs
{
    //imageView is a UIImageView which will be the return value of this function
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed@"blank1.gif"]];

    //Initialize label and manipulate it for my needs
    UILabel * label = /.../;  
     label.tag=10;

    [imageView addSubView:label];
    return imageView;
}
```

After call this function read label with tag 10 from imageview
and then apply animation code on that label.